# change the loading status of button in antd library with React state

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have been trying this functionality when you click on the button its loading status toggles between loading and not loading in Antd library which seems not working.

```
const NavBar = ()=>{
    const [initState,setState ] = useState({status : false});

    const clickHandler = (e)=>{
        setState({status : !initState.status})
        console.log(initState,initState.status)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button type="primary" loading={initState.status} onClick={clickHandler}>
                CLick me 
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I think the logic to do is fine. why is it not working does the control of loading works only one time?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that after the loading is set to true, your button is disabled, so you can't click it again and change the status, you must change it from somewhere else.